# Search bar in Office 365 is not returning any results for specific user, on specific SharePoint Online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

We have an individual user who has access to multiple SharePoint Online sites within the organisation as an Owner.  For most of the sites, that user is able to use the top Search bar in order to find results (including documents, etc).

However, when they are on using one particular Group Enabled site, the search bar returns absolutely no results for any query, even though they are an Owner on that site.  If they click on "Show more results", SharePoint comes up with no results.  The user is able to find the required documents by manually navigating to the associated Document Library, so they clearly have the required permissions.

Before I submit this to Microsoft for further troubleshooting, I wanted to see if there was anything obvious I was missing.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is related to everything on one site you could try going to **Site Settings** --> **Search and Offline Availability** and check if the `Allow this site to appear in search results` is set to **Yes**.

If it's only related to a document library on the site, go to **Library Settings** --> **Advanced Settings** and check if `Allow items from this document library to appear in search results` is set to **Yes**

Comment: Thanks, I had a look and both those settings were already set to Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyone who has changed the search settings such as result sources (please set Local SharePoint Results as default)? Does search bar work for other libraries or lists?

You could select Reindex Document Library to make sure that all content in the document library is indexed during the next scheduled crawl. Or reindex site in Search and Offline Availability.

Comment: The search works fine on this site for everyone else, except for this one individual user.